# SPID blocking processes on other databases where the query is not selecting from

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, blocking

We have a web application using a database. When there are concurrent users using the web we are experiencing a slow performance.

When tracing the queries running we identified there is frequent blocking happening and the strange issue is that these SPID block multiple processes EVEN the processes that are on different databases in the same server.

We have checked the select and it is purely selecting on that database and no linkage to the other.

Can someone please help on how I can trace how this is happening

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (This isn't really related to the <sql> _language.)

Comment: MS SQl Server - checking through SSMS

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Re "selecting on that database and no linkage to the other" - but the other way? Has any of blocked processes querying data from blocking database?

Comment: Try the actual documentation about [resolving blocking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/understand-resolve-blocking) as a first step

Comment: This script is very good for showing blocking chains https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/04/20/sql-server-blocking-tree-identifying-blocking-chain-using-sql-scripts/ you want to check exactly what resource is being waited on. The only thing I can think of is a trigger that is accessing some shared data, such as the `master` database, or possibly waiting on a latch for `tempdb`